# Is the address 183.91.128.161 a network, host or broadcast address?

Tags: networking, ip

I am currently going through some work I have got stuck at theses questions, is anybody able to point me in the right direction, a example would be brilliant.

```
IP Address given - 183.91.104.17
Subnet mask 255.255.0.0

Is the address 183.91.128.161 a network, host or broadcast address
Is the address 183.91.255.192 a network, host or broadcast address 
Is the address 183.91.95.224 a network, host or broadcast address 
Is the address 183.91.85.63 a network, host or broadcast address
```

Comment: This sounds like homework... What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is homework and I'm stuck, I'm not asking for the answers just some guidance in the right direction, is that wrong ? I have the gotten the network address and broadcast number of hosts ect...

Comment: Seriously, hit the books more... this is basic TCP/IP stuff and if this is what you're studying, you need to understand it for sure. `Is the address 183.91.128.161 a network, host or broadcast address` This is a SINGLE IP address.  Is a SINGLE IP address a NETWORK or a BROADCAST? Think about this a little more if the question is really as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a [look](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=B):

The IP Subnet Mask Calculator enables subnet network calculations using network class, IP address, subnet mask, subnet bits, mask bits, maximum required IP subnets and maximum required hosts per subnet.

[image]